# Passing Hash Table/Dictionary with a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, hashtable, dropdown

However, I want pass an "ID" into the option "value" field with a corresponding string as the option text.

So, if ID for Black = 1, White = 2, Blue = 3, then the html would look something like this:

```
<option value ='1'> Black </option>
```

This JSFiddle is similar to what I'm trying to accomplish:

http://jsfiddle.net/e6hzj8gx/4/

Except that I want to send only the value and use a key to call it.

I'm basically building a dropdown with Django that is dependent on what the user selects in another dropdown - there isn't really an elegant way of doing this in Django and it seems that serializing my data to json and then using javascript to build the drop down is the way to go.

My Django data is just a dict:

```
data = {1: 'Black', 2 = 'White', 3 = 'Blue'}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to loop through a javascript object. When working with a parsed JSON object, you can use:

```
for (var propName in obj) {
  // access data using obj[propName]
}
```

In more complicated cases, you might have to check if the property isn't inherited from some other prototype using:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName) { /* ... */ }
```

Furthermore, you can create DOM elements using `document.createElement("option")`

All together, it'll be something like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(serverData);
for (var propName in obj) {
  var jsonValue = obj[propName];
  if (jsonValue && (typeof jsonValue === "string")) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = propName;
    option.innerText = jsonValue;

    // Add created option to a select element
    // ...
  }
}
```

Let me know if I got your question right...

Comment: you may want to check if obj[propName] is defined first or is a string. doing a for on an object can have a final undefined.

Comment: @adrianj98, Valid point. I've updated the code with a defined/empty/string check.